redpanda connect deserialize json string
I have a Redpanda connect configuration to read a message from AWS SQS and write it down to DynamoDB. But dynamoDB all attributes in the document has null values because the message I read from SQS has backslashes. I believe Redpanda connect couldn't handle (or deserialize) it properly hence I end up with null values. I couldn't find how to deserialize my input to json.
Message
{
  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",
  \"MessageId\" : \"bla\",
  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:bla\",
  \"Subject\" : \"blabla\",
  \"Message\" : \"{\\\"RestaurantId\\\":000,\\\"Info\\\":{\\\"Id\\\":000,\\\"Name\\\":\\\"testtest\\\",\\\"BrandName\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"SeoName\\\":\\\"testtest\\\",\\\"Address\\\":{\\\"FirstLine\\\":\\\"MyAddress\\\",\\\"City\\\":\\\"Testcity\\\"
.
.
.
}

Redpanda Connect Configuration
input:
  aws_sqs:
    url: ${SQS_QUEUE_URL}
    region: eu-west-1

pipeline:
  processors:
    - log:
        level: DEBUG
        message: "Raw input: ${!content()}"

    - log:
        level: INFO
        fields_mapping: |
          root.name = this.Info.Name
          root.phone = this.Info.PhoneNumber
          root.branchName = this.Info.BrandName
          root.timeZone = this.Info.TimeZone
          root.street = this.Info.Address.FirstLine
          root.postalCode = this.Info.Address.Postcode
          root.city = this.Info.Address.City
          root.latitude = this.Info.Address.Location.Lat
          root.longitude = this.Info.Address.Location.Lng
        message: "Processing input"

output:
  aws_dynamodb:
    table: ${DYNAMODB_TABLE}
    batching:
      count: 10
      period: 1s
    json_map_columns:
      "": .
    region: eu-west-1

logger:
  level: DEBUG


The following Bloblang code should let you decode that message:
let content = "\"" + content() + "\""
root = $content.replace_all("\n","").unquote().parse_json()

Stick the above in a mapping processor.
Note that I used "\"" + content() + "\"" because your input message isn't surrounded by quotes, which seems wrong, but not sure.

Indeed I stripped the content from the quotes. Thanks for your advise :)
